# Extract all data in a query and some from another query

Tags: mysql, join

I have two queries.

**1st query**

```
SELECT A.ID1, A.ID2, B.ID3, B.approved FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID2 = B.ID2
```

This is the result:

```
ID1        ID2       ID3      approved
ABC        A01       B01        5
ABC        A01       B03        7
ABC        A01       B05        11
DEF        A02       B05        50
DEF        A02       B06        50
```

**2nd query**

```
SELECT C.ID1, C.ID3, C.requested FROM C
```

This is the result:

```
ID1        ID3     requested
ABC        B01        10
ABC        B02        20
ABC        B03        30
ABC        B04        40
ABC        B05        50
DEF        B02        99
DEF        B05        88
DEF        B01        77
DEF        B06        66
```

This is my expected result:

```
ID1        ID2       ID3    requested      approved
ABC        A01       B01       10             5
ABC        A01       B02       20             0
ABC        A01       B03       30             7
ABC        A01       B04       40             0
ABC        A01       B05       50            11
DEF        A02       B05       88            50
DEF        A02       B06       66            50
DEF        A02       B01       77             0
```

My query that not showing expected result:

```
    SELECT 
    C.ID1, C.ID3, C.requested,X.approved
FROM 
    C 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT 
                A.ID1, A.ID2, B.ID3, B.approved 
            FROM 
                A
            INNER JOIN 
                B 
            ON 
                A.ID2 = B.ID2)X  
ON C.ID3 = X.ID3
```

**Edit:**
When using Tim solution, this is the result:

```
    ID1        ID2       ID3    requested      approved
    ABC        A01       B01       10             5
    NULL       NULL      B02       20             0
    ABC        A01       B03       30             7
    NULL       NULL      B04       40             0
    ABC        A01       B05       50            11
    NULL       NULL      B02       99             0
    NULL       NULL      B01       77             0
    DEF        A02       B05       88            50
    DEF        A02       B06       66            50
    NULL       NULL      B01       77             0
```

When I use Order By the NULL is grouped. I don't know which NULL belong to which ID1 or ID2

Comment: Join through all 3 columns

Comment: Your updated results are not achievable from any join operation of which I'm aware.

Comment: Why does `ABC B02 20` appear in the result set but not `DEF B01 77` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ah yes. DEF B01 77  should appear too.

Comment: So basically, I'd like to show approved  = 0 for item that is not approved (not appear in first query)

Answer (score 0):

Your current query almost looks right, except that it uses `INNER JOIN` which will lop off records from `C` which don't match your first join query.  Also, the join condition between `C` and the join query is that both `ID1` and `ID3` should match.  Try this:

```
SELECT t2.ID1,
       t2.ID2,
       t1.ID3,
       t1.requested,
       COALESCE(t2.approved, 0)
FROM C t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT A.ID1, A.ID2, B.ID3, B.approved
    FROM A INNER JOIN B
        ON A.ID2 = B.ID2
) t2
    ON t1.ID1 = t2.ID1 AND
       t1.ID3 = t2.ID3
```

Comment: there are NULL values. and if there are more data the row with the NULLS is combined when I use ORDER BY

Comment: The NULL values are in column ID1 and ID2. This column should be filled with data (ABC and A01).

Comment: Are you looking for a full outer join?  Please show data which represents the actual problem (you haven't done this).